# How to correctly display html section onto a canvas with an background image?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm trying to show some formatted html onto a canvas with an image as background. The problem is that when I draw the HTML code on the canvas the html section it's shown very small and not formatted correctly.

This is the code generating that image.

```
        var ctx;
        var targetImg;
        const base_image = new Image();
        const {body} = document
        const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
        canvas.width =722;
        canvas.height = 458;
        base_image.src = 'https://imgur.com/1HTlrk1';
        base_image.onload = function() {
            ctx.drawImage(base_image,0,0,722,458);
            startDraw();
        };


        function startDraw() {

            const tempImg = document.createElement('img')
            tempImg.addEventListener('load', onTempImageLoad)
            tempImg.src = 'data:image/svg+xml,' + encodeURIComponent(
                '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="722px" height="458px">'+
                    '<foreignObject width="722px" height="458px">'+
                        '<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">'+
                            '<div style="width: 722px; background-color:transparent;height: 458px;">'+
                               '<div style="float:right; width:361px; display: block;position: absolute;left: 447px;top: 69px;">'+
                                   '<h1>Buscamos</h1>'+
                                    '<span>Team Leader</span>'+
                                    '<div style="width:300px;">'+
                                        'La busqueda se orienta a <b>desarrolladores Especialistas en Salesforce</b> <br/>con ingles avanzado y con experiencia en liderazgo de equipos'+
                                    '</div>'+
                                    '<table><tr><td>ANGULAR</td></tr></table></div></div></div></foreignObject></svg>');
            targetImg = document.createElement('img')
            body.appendChild(targetImg)
        }


    function onTempImageLoad(e){
      ctx.drawImage(e.target, 0, 0);
      targetImg.src = canvas.toDataURL();
    }
```

I'm thinking the html I'm drawing on the canvas it's not correctly formatted as a XHTMl block

Comment: Dear god son! Why are you not using string literals? Am I missing something, but are you trying to encode a bunch of HTML with encodeURIComponent?

Comment: What do you mean string literals? But yes that's what I'm doing, It's the way I found to embed formatted html onto a canvas. This is a proof of concept, when this is solved the text on the image will be dynamic.

Comment: My mistake, "template literals". Makes it so you dont have to connect a bunch of things with "+". 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Also, it would help if you could provide a jsfiddle or codepen link with the code in it for us to see what you are seeing and to provide better help.